# Python multiprocessing function error with sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, sparse-matrix

i have the following input data:

```
In [206]: response
Out[206]: 
<8593x5071 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
with 85835 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I wrote the following function:

```
def cosine_sim(response):
    cos_sim = []
    for i in range(response.get_shape()[0]):
        cos = cosine_similarity(response, response[i])
        cos_sim.append((-np.sort(-np.delete(cos, i, 0), axis = 0)[0:10].mean()).astype("float16"))
    return cos_sim
```

The function works fine and does what it is supposed to do. However, i want to use multiprocessing. As multiprocessing works on my Spyder only if I import a function, i saved the function from above in a separate script as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def cosine_sim(response):
    cos_sim = []
    for i in range(response.get_shape()[0]):
        cos = cosine_similarity(response, response[i])
        cos_sim.append((-np.sort(-np.delete(cos, i, 0), axis = 0)[0:10].mean()).astype("float16"))
return cos_sim
```

If I import the function and call it w/o multiprocessing, it just works fine as before. I then use the following code to start multiprocessing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
with Pool(processes=12) as pool:
    app_start_time = time.time()
    cos_sim_imported = pool.map(cos_sim_script.cosine_sim, response)
    print(time.time() - app_start_time)
```

I then get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

Input In [205] in <cell line: 1>
    cos_sim_imported = pool.map(cos_sim_script.cosine_sim, response)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py:364 in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py:478 in _map_async
    chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py:291 in __len__
    raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"

TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

Can somebody tell me why the function works w/o multiprocessing, but not with? In case somebody is wondering why i not simply use the pairwise cosine simialrity for this problem, i normally have larger input data where my RAM is not sufficient.

Best

Answer (score 0):

Your own code uses `shape[0]` to get the iteration range.  I think the multiprocessing assumes the input is a list, or list like, and uses `len`.

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse
In [2]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.eye(3))
In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [4]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
In [5]: M.shape
Out[5]: (3, 3)
In [6]: len(M)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [6] in <cell line: 1>
    len(M)
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_base.py:345 in __len__
raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

I haven't done much with multiprocessing, but you may need to split the sparse matrix into a list of matrices

```
In [8]: list(M)
Out[8]: 
[<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

Compared to doing the same with a dense array, this is pretty slow:

```
In [9]: timeit list(M)
219 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
In [10]: timeit list(M.A)
10.5 µs ± 58.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```